# C#: Inherit and override property

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual

I have a class Base which is like:-

```
class Base 
{
    public virtual string a=>SomeMethod(a);
}
```

I need to override the variable a in Base.

```
class Derived: Base 
{
    public string a ="Hello";
}
```

Is this correct?What is the correct way to inherit from Base and override the value of a?
Thanks!

Comment: You're asking how to use the `override` keyword?  No your code is not correct.  `a` in your base class is a property.  In your derived class it's a field.

Comment: `public override string a => "Hello";`

Comment: Do you get an error? What error says?

Comment: Amy is right! You can't override a property like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use the keyword 'override'. However, you cannot use it on fields. If you want to override the virtual property in your base class, create a corressponding property in your derived class.

```
class Derived: Base 
{
    public override string a => "Hello";
}
```

Comment: You did more than just add the `override` keyword.  Might be worth noting to the OP why this is different because simply adding `override` to the OP's code won't fix their problem

Comment: @maccettura You are right. I will add some clarification.